# Perl open file with variable in name

Tags: perl

Why is this example not working?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use POSIX qw(strftime);
use Time::Local;

my $date = strftime "%Y-%m-%d", localtime;
my $command = "ls clients/*/ERRORi/" . $date . "/*s";

@result = `$command`;

foreach $group (@result) {
  my $file = '/opt/' . $group;
  open( my $input_fh, '<', $file) || die "Can't open $file: $!";
  print $input_fh;
}
```

it will return:

```
Can't open /opt/clients/cli8832/ERRORi/2014-06-25/file.564159972s
: No such file or directory at ./my.pl line 12.
```

but if I do `ls /opt/clients/cli8832/ERRORi/2014-06-25/file.564159972s` it works

Comment: The formatting of the error message is a good clue here. Your `$file` has a newline in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a poor example to be learning from.

- Include [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`use warnings`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) in EVERY perl script.
- Include [`use autodie;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/autodie.html) anytime you're doing file processing
- And finally, instead of shelling out to `ls`, just use a file [`glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html).  This will remove the need to [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html).

Then following is a cleaned up version of that example, although the last line is probably also a bug.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use POSIX qw(strftime);
use Time::Local;

my $date = strftime "%Y-%m-%d", localtime;

for my $group (glob "clients/*/ERRORi/$date/*s") {
    my $file = '/opt/' . $group;
    open my $input_fh, '<', $file;
    print $input_fh;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Your `$file` variable contains a trailing linefeed character, whereas your actual file name doesn't.

Your ought to `chomp` it out.